# Is setContentView necessary when finish is called

Tags: android, android-activity

Lets assume that I am going to not show activity conditionally, so I will use `finish()` in `onCreate()`. Do I have to to call `setContentView()` before calling `finish()`? The below code is what I going to do. Is it a correct way to do this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (condition) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView statusTextView = findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);
    statusTextView.setText("bla bla...");
}
```

Comment: NO. Its not necessary. Prevent the `Activity` not to open at all with `Intent` if you can . Otherwise this is ok .

Comment: also **`return;`** is not  required

Comment: why do you want to go to a new activity if you want to finish it after launching?

Comment: @NileshRathod Of course `return` is required if OP does not want to continue executing code in `onCreate()`. Calling `finish()` does not stop the method from continuing to execute. A `return` statement after calling `finish()` is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not necessary to call `setContentView()`. You can finish your activity directly.

Yes we can return it to another activity based on condition.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not necessary to call `setContentView()` method. It is call to show the UI but in your case you just want to finish the activity without showing the UI, So it is fine.